# weird rvm list output

Tags: macos, rvm, zsh

I'm getting this error when i do 'rvm list' command. I'm using oh-my-zsh, but loading it both in bash and zsh, I'm still getting the same error.

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ x86_64 ]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bash error message, but weirdly rendered because the message contains a carriage return. In fact bash was displaying

```
bash: 42: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "␍")
```

where ␍ is a carriage return. If you have a carriage return in a file, it's probably because it uses DOS/Windows line endings (CR+LF). Convert it to unix line endings (LF only).